# tab bar inheritance behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, storyboard

I have a tab bar controller. The first item of the tab bar is table view controller, and it is getting the tab bar itens from the parent tab bar controller. Now I'm connecting a view controller to the cells of the table view controller, but it does not get the tab bar.

So:

```
Tab bar
  Table view
    View
```

How can I keep the tab bar in the view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My storyboard is:

UINavigationController > UITabBar > UITableViewController > UIViewController

It works if I change to:

UITabBar > UINavigationController > UITableViewController > UIViewController

And use:

```
UIViewController *c = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
[c setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [indexPath row]]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
```

I tried to find the pushViewController: method in the tabController but a tabController does not have one, so I tried to change the order of the controllers and it works.